# Datepicker (1.8rc3) not transferring date in IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer

Using jquery-1.4.2 and jquery-UI 1.8rc3, I instantiated a datepicker on a text input with showOn: 'focus'.   The datepicker appears correctly.  However when I click on a date, the datepicker doesn't disappear and the dateStr doesn't get transferred to the text input.  I tried adding an onClose: handler that calls alert(dateStr). The event fires but no dateStr has been set.  Everything works fine in Firefox.   I have Microsoft Script Debugger installed but no script errors were detected.

I did report this as a potential problem at the jQuery UI forums but my message has been sitting there awaiting moderation for hours and I figured someone here might have a suggestion.

```
$().ready(function() {
$(".date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'focus',
    onClose: function(dateText) {
        alert(dateText);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: I found your bug...you said IE6 :)  Actually, I believe this is a known bug in 1.8rc3, however...the ticket system is down at the moment (and how do you report *that*?)  If I get a tweet back saying it's up I'll try and update this.

Comment: I am seeing this as well. I have just upgraded to the latest UI version after having successfully used the previous 1.7.x. I am very keen for a fix having just spent three days tidying up our js code based on the upgrade!

Answer (score -1):

Seriously. Don't support IE6. You're just perpetuating the stereotype that its an acceptable browser.

Comment: That answer wasn't even remotely helpful.  The truth is that this is for a corporate client with an enormous installation of workstations that are running Windows XP with IE6. I have absolutely zero influence on whether they will, or won't, upgrade, and to them it's just "the Internet" and all their other apps work in it.

Comment: Yup, I agree with brianjchohen.  Unfortunately, the bigger the corporate client, the more likely they are still locked into using IE6.

Comment: I whole-heartedly disagree with both of you and have good reason to back that up.

Regardless of whatever enterprise bubble you may be stuck in, Microsoft ended mainstream support for IE6 in 2001 (!!!), 12 years ago. If your company is still using it, then they're putting themselves at risk with regard to security updates. If you're still developing on it, then you're most likely neutering your product for the sake of said company's refusal to upgrade.

My answer is correct, push for change here. If your company is investing in something old and dangerous, it's time to re-invest.

Comment: No one will ever upgrade until you give them good reason too, make your product the carrot at the end of the stick that they just can't live without, stand back, and watch change happen. Lastly, no one outside of those forced too is going to optimize their code for a browser from 12 years ago. Expect problems, and very little sympathy if you can't convince the powers that be to invest time in some upgrades :(